# Django select multiple model instances of the same user

Tags: python, django

I have this:

```
user = request.user
notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=user)
budget = Budget.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Is there a way to get this data into one query? I was looking into a Subquery or a join query, but I don't know if it can be done. Any idea?

Comment: Can you share your models

Answer (score 1):

user following:

```
from itertools import chain

user = request.user
notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=user)
budget = Budget.objects.filter(user=user)

result = list(chain(notifications, budget))
```

also you can use following:

```
from django.db.models import Q

result = (Q(notifications) | Q(budget))
```

Comment: im looking for a way to grab both the notifications and budgets for a user into one query, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: you can use the Q class from db this will combine both querysets as you expecting in one queryset